# Why a set or vector start counting from a negative or zero index?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, vectors

I am reading a paper which sets $V_{-1}$ := *R* and $V_{m+1} \subset V_m$ for all $m \ge -1$.

As I know that a vector is normally counted as $V_1, V_2,...,V_n,$ so what dose this $V_{-1}$ meaning? Why count starting from $-1$? I am sorry that this question maybe too general, but I am really confused about this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's just an index, for labeling or counting.

Comment: I agree with you, but I think that if counted starting from 1 maybe better?  So I think there is some other meaning ?

Comment: Most mathematicians and computer scientists agree that it is better to start counting at zero. Then the $-1$ case is somehow the degenerate case or setup case.

Comment: But if I am coding it, I cant count it from zero or $-1$. Or I just treat the $V_{-1}$ and $V_0$ as $V_1$ and $V_2$ respectively?

Comment: yes that will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can talk about a collection of vectors $\{V_i\}_{i\in I}$, where $I$ is some set. $I$ can be $\{1,\ldots,n\},\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z}$ or even an uncountable set.

In your case it must be countable, because you have $V_{m+1} \subset V_m$.

Usually they start counting from $m=-1$, because $m$ is used in another calculation, or because $m=0$ is a special case.

Comment: So this means $V_{-1}$ has same attribute as $V_1$ that both of them are the subset of $V_m$?

Comment: @zdeng The opposite is true (for $m\geq 1$). In total: $V_{-1}\supset V_0\supset V_1\supset V_2\supset \ldots$.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are right. It says that $m={-1,0,1}$ are the special cases.